# Why have i lost my monero money? my wallet is fully synched and no sign of it

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, blockchain, payment-id

I sent monero to my monero wallet and hasn't appeared yet. I used a payment id even when I didnt have to. The money is nowwhere to befound. I located the blockchain height it is confirmed at 1,0523,091. This is from blockchain radar. I have my gui wallet fully synched past this block height. Have i lost my money forever? I did everything right from what i can see. Please any suggestions. Im very frustrated.

Comment: Use that ^ guide to resolve your issue.

Comment: Hey thank you for the help! I used your guide and followed the directions. I still cant see my money. Its confirmed on the blockchain but. cant receive it. Is it really gone forever? Im pretty stressed out. If you can offer any more help i would appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: Is your blockchain fully synced? If so, go to the `Settings` page and change the `Wallet creation height` (under `Debug info`) to `1400000` | Subsequently, let the wallet refresh until it states `Connected`

Comment: Thank you so much fro your help! I found the Monero. really appreciate you helping me!